# How to get the File Extension from a string Path

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got file path saved in variable and I want to get the file type extension by using path package https://pub.dev/packages/path So far I managed to do it by splitting the string like this

```dart
final path = "/some/path/to/file/file.dart";
print(path.split(".").last); //prints dart
```

Is there any way to achieve this with path package?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use the [`extension` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/extension.html) in the [`path` package](https://pub.dev/packages/path) to get the extension from a file path:

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

final path = '/some/path/to/file/file.dart';

final extension = p.extension(path); // '.dart'
```

If your file has multiple extensions, like `file.dart.js`, you can specify the optional `level` parameter:

```dart
final extension = p.extension('file.dart.js', 2); // '.dart.js'
```

Comment: is there also any way to use that path package to get also file type.. let's say if the file is an image, document and so on? I doubt that it is possible but if so I will create another question for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361613/how-to-get-type-of-file

Answer (score 10):

No need of any extension. You can try below code snippet.

```
String getFileExtension(String fileName) {
try {
  return "." + fileName.split('.').last;
 } catch(e){
  return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: You code will throw if there is no extension. The path package is a better idea and had lots of other uses.

Comment: Added a Try catch block, that will solve your issue.

Comment: again, use the path package. It will save much pain and suffering.

Answer (score 1):

This small function can parse filepath or url and find basename, extension and absolute path. It doesn't check file path exist and not check basename is folder or file.

```
  Map parsePath(String filepath) {
    Map p1 = new Map();
    int ind1 = filepath.indexOf("://");
    if (ind1 > 0) {
      p1["fullpath"] = filepath;
    } else {
      p1["fullpath"] = File(filepath).absolute.path;
    }
    p1["path"] = filepath;
    List<String> v = filepath.split("/");
    if (v.length > 1) {
      p1["basename"] = v.last;
    } else if (filepath.split("\\").length > 1) {
      p1["basename"] = filepath.split("\\").last;
    } else {
      p1["basename"] = v.last;
    }
    p1["extension"] = p1["basename"].split('.').last;
    if (p1["basename"] == p1["extension"]) p1["extension"] = "";
    return p1;
  }
```