# How to scan and get list of all files with specific extension from root storage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a pdf reader app. I want to scan for all files in the storage and only display those files that end with extension '.pdf' in a listview with name and size of the file. How can i achieve this?

Comment: from android 12, 13+ you cannot ask the permission to read all files from root storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FilePicker for the files you want to pick.
[This](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) is the package link.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
   type: FileType.custom,
   allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
);
```

Comment: thanks though i don't want to pick but i want them to appear just when user opens the device in a listview like only pdfs from the device storage. like getAllPdfsFromDeviceStorage() in the initState(). Would you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For any given directory you can use the listSync() method to see all the files present in it. And after that you could simply check the file extension from file name either by string:

```
file.path.substring(file.path.length - 4) == '.pdf';
```

or using the [How to get the File Extension from a string Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358216/how-to-get-the-file-extension-from-a-string-path)